# I'm displaying a gauge chart in my site and the chart is inside a loop. But the chart is displayed only once. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have placed this following code inside a loop and the chart is not displaying as desired.I have used google gauge chart to display the age of  University. I have also attached the screenshot for more reference.
[image]

```
                          <h5>Age of &nbsp;<span class="text-primary"><?php echo $uni_name; ?></span></h5>
                         <?php 
                             $est=date('Y')-$uni_establish;
                         ?>
                            <p style="font-family: Serif; font-size: 170px; color:green; align:center"><b><?php echo $est;?></b></p>
                                 <script type="text/javascript">
                                    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
                                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                                    function drawChart() {

                                      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                        ['Label', 'Value'],
                                        ['Age', <?php echo $est;?>],
                                      ]);

                                      var options = {
                                        width: 600, height: 320,
                                        yelloFrom: 0, yellowTo: 100,
                                        minorTicks: 5
                                      };

                                      var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


                                      chart.draw(data, options);

                                    }
                                  </script>

                          <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 320px;"></div>

                    </section>
```

Comment: If this code is inside the loop means div with id chart_div will be appear multiple times, use an increment variable @Sujith

Comment: @parth mahida: Thanks, It works perfect. :)

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer as best @Sujith

Answer (score 0):

If this code is inside the loop means div with id chart_div will be appear multiple times, use an increment variable.